# A classic card problem.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Two cards are missing from a pack of cards, and one is drawn. The probability that this card is a king is?

My solution so far-

If no king is missing, the probability of drawing a king is $4/50$.
If one king is missing, the probability is $3/50$, and if two are missing, it becomes $2/50$.

Since all these cases are possible, we add them up, to get $9/50$. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: the chances of zero kings missing is (48 / 52) x (47 / 51) - that is to say, we took away one of 48 non-kings, then from the reduced pack of 51, we took one of 47 non kings

Comment: the chances of 2 kings missing is (4 / 52) x (3 / 51) - that is to say we took a king both times

Comment: the chances of 1 king missing is that we took a king then not a king or not a king then a king - they are independent so we can add them (4/52)(48/51) + (48/52)(4/51)   - so now you can weight your 3 correct probabilities

Comment: Alright, @Andrew. That makes it easier for me to understand. 1/13 it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to look at this is to think of drawing three cards in a row. The first two will be designated as "missing", and you want to find the probability that the third card is a king. The probability is the same as the probability of any card being a king, which is 1/13.

Comment: Could you elaborate on, "The probability is the same as any card being a king, which is 1/13"?

Comment: when you take the two cards out, you don't check to see what they were, so imagine all the 52 cards in front of you face down, and someone moves two of them to another part of the table - now nothing has changed, any of those 52 cards is equally likely to be a KING, whether in the 2 or the remaining 50.  The action of moving two cards conveyed no information about the cards, so if you choose a card at random it is 1/52 it will be any particular card, ergo 4/52 that it is a king.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

You cannot just add them up. 
You have to assign a weight to the result of each case (i.e. $4/50,3/50,\dots$), where the weight is the probability for that case. For instance, is the case that two kings are missing just as likely as the case that only one king is missing? Probably not. Try to work out the probabilities for each scenario.

If it is still causing you trouble, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If the two cards removed contain no king then the probability of then probability of getting a king from the 50 cards is

$$ {P_1} = \left( {\frac{{48}}{{52}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{47}}{{51}}} \right)\left( {\frac{4}{{50}}} \right) $$

If the two cards removed contain one king then the probability of then probability of getting a king from the 50 cards is

$$ {P_2} = 2\left( {\frac{4}{{52}}} \right)\left( {\frac{{48}}{{51}}} \right)\left( {\frac{3}{{50}}} \right) $$

If the two cards removed are both kings then the probability of then probability of getting a king from the 50 cards is

$$ {P_3} = \left( {\frac{4}{{52}}} \right)\left( {\frac{3}{{51}}} \right)\left( {\frac{2}{{50}}} \right) $$

So the probability that you will get a king from the 50 remaining cards is:

$$ {P_1} + {P_2} + {P_3} = \frac{{10200}}{{132600}} = \frac{1}{{13}} $$

as others have pointed out.